# Collapse array-building nested each loops into single reduce in Ruby

Tags: ruby, optimization, functional-programming

I'm trying to minimize procedural code in Ruby. I have the following function `build_array`. It procedurally builds up a `array` in a pair of nested `each` loops.

```rb
  def build_array(max)
    array = []
    (1..max).each do |size|
      (0..size).each do |n|
        array << [n, size - n]
      end
    end
    array 
  end
```

The function works correctly and produces output like this:

```
> build_array 2
 => [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
> build_array 3
 => [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

Can this function be further optimized with a `reduce` somehow? The building up of a new object based on the result of a series of operations seems to fit that pattern, but I can't figure it out. The order of the subarrays is not important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this with `map` instead of `each` ... essentially the same code but you don't need to shovel it into an array as `map` returns an array for you.

```
def build_array(max)
  (1..max).map{|s|(0..s).map{|n|[n,s-n]}}.flatten(1)
end
```

`reduce` or the alias `inject` would require you to still insert into an array, so I can't see it would be better than your original method. I'd only use `reduce` if I wanted to return an object that consolidates the input array into a smaller collection.

Comment: Thank you--I think `flatten` was the missing key for me, since I was hung up on the fact that I wanted a 2-level instead of 3-level array. This is perfect.

Comment: If you change the first `map` to `flat_map` you can ditch `flatten(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this function be further optimized with a `reduce` somehow?

I don't know about "optimized", but yes, you definitely can use `reduce`. And I didn't even read your code before I answered!

There is an interesting reason why I was able to give that answer without even looking at your question, and that is that `reduce` is a *general iteration operator*. Now, what do I mean by that?

If you think about what `reduce` does, on a deep level, here is how it works. A collection can either be empty or not empty. Those are the only two cases. And the reduce operator takes three arguments:

- The collection being reduced,
- What to do when the collection is not empty, and
- What to do when the collection is empty.

Now, you might say "three arguments, I only see one", but that's because we are using Ruby:

- The first argument is the hidden `self` argument, i.e. the collection that you are calling `reduce` on,
- The second argument is the block, and
- The third argument is the *actual* argument that Ruby's `Enumerable#inject` takes.

Now, typically we think about, and call the third argument the "accumulator". But in some other languages, it is also called the "zero", and there you can more easily see the connection to processing an empty collection.

But think about it: when you iterator over a collection, you generally have to deal with the fact that the collection is empty. And you have to somehow produce the next step in case the collection is not empty. There is really nothing else you need to do when iterating.

But those two things are exactly what is being covered by the last two arguments of the reduce operator!

So, it turns out that `reduce` *can do everything that iteration can do*. Really, everything. Everything that can be done with `for` / `in` or `each` in Ruby, `foreach` in C#, `for` / `in`, `for` / `of`, and `forEach` in JavaScript, the enhanced `for` loop in Java and C++, etc. can be done with `reduce`.

That means that every method that exists in `Enumerable` can be done with `reduce`.

Another way to think about it, is that a collection is a *program* written in a language that has only two commands: `ELEMENT(x)` and `STOP`. And `reduce` is an *interpreter* for that programming language that allows you to customize and provide your own implementations of `ELEMENT(x)` and `STOP`.

That is why the answer to the question "can this iteration thing be done with `reduce`" is *always* "Yes", regardless of what the "thing" that you're doing actually is.

So, back to your question, here is what a naive, blind, mechanical 1:1 translation of your code to `reduce` would look like:

```rb
def build_array(max)
  (1..max).reduce([]) do |acc, size|
    (0..size).reduce(acc) do |acc, n|
      acc << [n, size - n]
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever you have a code pattern of the form:

- Create some object
- Iterate over a collection and add to that object in each iteration
- Return the object

That is *exactly* `reduce`: the object that you are creating is the accumulator and your loop body is the reducing operation. You can see that here:
[image: Comparison of before and after code.]

Note that in general `reduce` is considered to be part of functional programming, and we are actually mutating the accumulator here. It would be more "pure" to instead return a new accumulator in each iteration:

```rb
def build_array(max)
  (1..max).reduce([]) do |acc, size|
    (0..size).reduce(acc) do |acc, n|
      acc + [[n, size - n]]
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, Ruby also has an "impure" version of `reduce` called `each_with_object` that is specifically designed for mutating the accumulator. In particular, `reduce` uses the return value of the block as the accumulator object for the next iteration, whereas `each_with_object` always passes the same object and just ignores the return value of the block:

```rb
def build_array(max)
  (1..max).each_with_object([]) do |size, array|
    (0..size).each_with_object(array) do |n, array|
      array << [n, size - n]
    end
  end
end
```

However, note that just because everything *can* be expressed as a `reduce` operation, not everything *should* be expressed as a `reduce` operation. There are several more specific operations, and if possible, those should be used.

In particular, in our case we are actually mostly *transforming* values, and that's what `map` is for. Or, `flat_map` if you want to process a nested collection into a non-nested one:

```rb
def build_array(max)
  (1..max).flat_map do |size|
    (0..size).map do |n|
      [n, size - n]
    end
  end
end
```

However, the most elegant solution in my opinion is the recursive one:

```rb
def build_array(max)
  return [] if max.zero?

  build_array(max.pred) + (0..max).map do |n|
    [n, max - n]
  end
end
```

However, note that this solution might be blow the stack for high values of `max`. Although that may or may not be a problem in your case because the result array also grows pretty large very quickly, so at the point where you run out of stack space, you pretty much also would run out of RAM, even with a non-recursive solution. On my laptop with YARV, I was able to determine that it breaks somewhere between 10000 and 20000, at which point the array uses well over 1GB.

The solution for this is to use a lazy infinite stream that generates each element one-by-one as it is consumed:

```rb
build_array = Enumerator.new do |y|
  (1..).each do |size|
    (0..size).each do |n|
      y << [n, size - n]
    end
  end
end

loop do
  print build_array.next
end
# [0, 1][1, 0][0, 2][1, 1][2, 0][0, 3][1, 2][2, 1][3, 0][0, 4][1, 3][2, 2]
# [3, 1][4, 0][0, 5][1, 4][2, 3][3, 2][4, 1][5, 0][0, 6][1, 5][2, 4][3, 3]
# [4, 2][5, 1][6, 0][0, 7][1, 6][2, 5][3, 4][4, 3][5, 2][6, 1][7, 0][0, 8]
# [1, 7][2, 6][3, 5][4, 4][5, 3][6, 2][7, 1][8, 0][0, 9][1, 8][2, 7][3, 6]
# [4, 5][5, 4][6, 3][7, 2][8, 1][9, 0][0, 10][1, 9][2, 8][3, 7][4, 6][5, 5]
# [6, 4][7, 3][8, 2][9, 1][10, 0][0, 11][1, 10][2, 9][3, 8][4, 7][5, 6][6, 5]
# [7, 4][8, 3][9, 2][10, 1][11, 0][0, 12][1, 11][2, 10][3, 9][4, 8][5, 7]
# [6, 6][7, 5][8, 4][9, 3][10, 2][11, 1][12, 0][0, 13][1, 12][2, 11]
# [3, 10][4, 9][5, 8][6, 7][7, 6][8, 5][9, 4][10, 3][11, 2][12, 1][13, 0]
# [0, 14][1, 13][2, 12][3, 11][4, 10][5, 9][6, 8][7, 7][8, 6][9, 5][10, 4]
# [11, 3][12, 2][13, 1][14, 0][0, 15][1, 14][2, 13][3, 12][4, 11][5, 10]
# [6, 9][7, 8][8, 7][9, 6][10, 5][11, 4][12, 3][13, 2][14, 1][15, 0]
# [0, 16][1, 15][2, 14][3, 13][4, 12][5, 11][6, 10][7, 9][8, 8][9, 7][10, 6]
# [11, 5][12, 4][13, 3][14, 2][15, 1][16, 0][0, 17][1, 16][2, 15][3, 14]
# [4, 13][5, 12][6, 11][7, 10][8, 9][9, 8][10, 7][11, 6][12, 5][13, 4][14, 3]
# [15, 2][16, 1][17, 0][0, 18][1, 17][2, 16][3, 15][4, 14][5, 13][6, 12]
# [7, 11][8, 10][9, 9][10, 8] …
```

You can let this run forever, it will never use any more memory. On my laptop, the Ruby process never grows beyond 9MB, where it was using multiple GB previously.

Comment: Very interesting read, especially about `reduce`, which I need to think about. Incidentally, I believe the number of 2-element arrays equals `max*(3+max)/2`, so `10000-20000` corresponds to about `50-200` million 2-element arrays.

Comment: A very interesting read indeed. This satisfies my feeling that it was fundamentally the reduce pattern at work. What's the trick to turning that vague feeling I had into a solution, to identifying fp patterns and using them? Just experience?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is mostly for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

But let's try to help you:
Here is example with [`Enumerable#inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) and [`Array#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-c-new)

```rb
def new_build_array(max)
  (1..max).inject([]) do |array, size|
    array += Array.new(size+1) { |e| [e, size-e] }
  end
end

> new_build_array 2
=> [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
> new_build_array 3
=> [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for point out Code Review, I didn't know of that. I appreciate a solution that uses reduce as I had imagined it working, yet I think SteveTurczyn's answer captures the solution even better.